# R.js and Coffeescript in Node

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, requirejs

New to node.  Can somebody help me understand how to use/configure r.js with coffeescript in a nodejs app?

To elaborate, I'm a little lost on a few things. Where to include r.js in the project. A simple use case of require and define with r.js. Where to include cs-require in the source. Which parts can be installed with npm install I asked this question earlier but it seemed as though I was asking 10 questions so I was trying to be more concise. I was hoping someone could point me to an example git because I'm having a hard time finding any.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend being a bit more specific about what you don't understand, or this question will likely be closed

Comment: I'm a little lost on a few things.  Where to include r.js in the project.  A simple use case of require and define with r.js.  Where to include cs-require in the source.  Which parts can be installed with `npm install` I asked this question earlier but it seemed as though I was asking 10 questions so I was trying to be more concise.  I was hoping someone could point me to an example git because I'm having a hard time finding any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install requirejs via

```
npm install requirejs
```

then you can use it's built-in 'r' function via the executable:

```
node_modules/bin/r
```

which you'll probably want to use as part of your backend build-script.

Comment: I've set something up like this but it doesn't seem to recognize my .coffee files.